Python LDAP3 error certificate verify failed: EE certificate key too weak
I have the following python code with the ldap3 library that I use to connect via LDAPS to an active directory:
    tls_configuration = Tls(
       validate=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
       version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2,
    )

    server = Server(
       SERVER,
       use_ssl=True,
       get_info=ALL,
       tls=tls_configuration
    )

    conn = Connection(
        server,
        auto_bind=False,
        user=USERNAME,
        password=PASSWORD,
        authentication=NTLM,
        raise_exceptions=True,
    )

    conn.bind()

    return conn

However, when doing such, it returns the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Code\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "Code\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\main.py", line 6, in main
    pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner.main()
  File "Code\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\src\pytoolsadinactiveempcleaner\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner.py", line 258, in main
    conn = get_ldap_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Code\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\src\pytoolsadinactiveempcleaner\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner.py", line 78, in get_ldap_connection
    conn.bind()
  File "Code\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\env\Lib\site-packages\ldap3\core\connection.py", line 589, in bind
    self.open(read_server_info=False)
  File "Code\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\env\Lib\site-packages\ldap3\strategy\sync.py", line 57, in open
    BaseStrategy.open(self, reset_usage, read_server_info)
  File "Code\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\env\Lib\site-packages\ldap3\strategy\base.py", line 146, in open
    raise exception_history[0][0]
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketOpenError: ("('socket ssl wrapping error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: EE certificate key too weak (_ssl.c:992)',)",)

From what I understand, the problem seems to be that the server certificate is too weak (1024 RSA). However I wanted to make sure. Also, the Ldap3 doc indicates that it is possible to use the SSLContext to manage the connection socket. However, there seems to be no usage example. I was wondering if you guys had any
I've tried modifying the ciphers to lower the accepted algorithm by modifying the above code as such:
    tls_configuration = Tls(
       validate=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
       version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2,
       ciphers='ALL:@SECLEVEL=1'
    )

However, the error then switches to this:
File "Code\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "Code\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\main.py", line 6, in main
    pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner.main()
  File "Code\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\src\pytoolsadinactiveempcleaner\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner.py", line 258, in main
    conn = get_ldap_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Code\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\src\pytoolsadinactiveempcleaner\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner.py", line 78, in get_ldap_connection
    conn.bind()
  File "Code\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\env\Lib\site-packages\ldap3\core\connection.py", line 628, in bind
    response = self.do_ntlm_bind(controls)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "\Code\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\env\Lib\site-packages\ldap3\core\connection.py", line 1398, in do_ntlm_bind
    response = self.post_send_single_response(self.send('bindRequest', request, controls))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Code\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\env\Lib\site-packages\ldap3\strategy\sync.py", line 160, in post_send_single_response
    responses, result = self.get_response(message_id)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Code\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\pytoolsad_inactive_emp_cleaner\env\Lib\site-packages\ldap3\strategy\base.py", line 403, in get_response
    raise LDAPOperationResult(result=result['result'], description=result['description'], dn=result['dn'], message=result['message'], response_type=result['type'])
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPInvalidCredentialsResult: LDAPInvalidCredentialsResult - 49 - invalidCredentials - None - 80090346: LdapErr: DSID-0C09072E, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 80090346, v3839 - bindResponse - None

Many thanks!

You're totally right! My mistake I did a bad copy paste. To answer your question I did check the certificate straight on our CA and it is a 1024.

The new error message is completely unrelated to the title of the question. It obviously does not fail SSL anymore but fails inside LDAP with invalidCredentials. This error message obviously points to wrong credentials (username, password).

I forgot to state but the credentials are verified and work when the certificate is not validated. This, in my opinion, clearly points towards a problem in the certificate.

"This, in my opinion, clearly points towards a problem in the certificate." - The TLS handshake was successful, because without it it could not start with the LDAP protocol inside the TLS session. So there is no problem at the TLS level, including no problem with the certificate. Also, the error it shows is generated by the server, so it successfully send the LDAP request to the server. If the same credentials work without TLS then this suggest that the server behaves differently when accessed by TLS vs non-TLS. To be sure just try with a different LDAP client.
